# how can i make curve-foggy background image overlay

Tags: css, background, overlay, linear-gradients

Firstly sorry. I cannot describe how I want my overlay to look exactly.

I am trying to make the overlay look like the **picture below**.

I have tried the following **code**:

```css
*,*::after,*::before{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        section{
            margin-left: auto;
            padding: 20px 100px;
        }
           .container{
            position: relative;
            min-width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            background: rgb(0, 64, 255);
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
       
        .developer-overlay{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            /* background:  linear-gradient(115deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801) 35%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.356) 80%,transparent 100%); */
            background:  radial-gradient(circle at -100%, #fff 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.685) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.363) 100%);;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
   <section>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="holder">
            <div class="developer-bg"></div>
            <div class="developer-overlay"></div>
          
           </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

**Picture**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask like below:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  border-radius:30px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1024/800/800) center/cover no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(100% 150% at right, #fff 40%,transparent 90%); 
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: i think it will resolve my issue. before ask this question i was thinking this question will resolve my  two problem but it is different question ,  is there any way to rotate mask 30,45 degree .  [for this overlay](https://i.imgur.com/SxUJovc.png). before ask i know i need to try it myself , thanks...

Comment: @noor replace the `at right` with `at 100% 50%` then increase/dcrease the 50% to get what you want

Comment: @noor and adjust the 150% to control the curve

Comment: [form the picture](https://i.imgur.com/SxUJovc.png) , I think curved top width smaller than curved bottom width

Comment: @noor yes, adjust the value like I told you and you can get it .. 100% 50% will make both the same, using 100% 40% will bottom bigger and so on